# pyqt: how to link pushbutton with different functions depending on how many times it been clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm

hey i trying to link my pushbutton with different functions, i defined a new button as follow:the first time clicked :print a; second time print b. However , the code does not work. no matter how many times button clicked, it only print "b".  thank you for the help !

```
def a():
    print("a")
def b():
    print("b")

class nextbutton(QPushButton):

    window.count += 1
    print(window.count)

    def function(self):
        if window.count == 1:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(a)
        else:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(b)

mybutton = nextbutton()
ui.next4.clicked.connect(mybutton.function)
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question here. What about this code does not work? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: hi this code does not work. since it only prints "b", without doing the counting

Comment: Please [Edit] the question and tell us there. Comments can be deleted. Have you read [ask] and taken the [tour]?

Comment: what is `window`? please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

#### Statement position

One issue is that you're not incrementing the count when the button is clicked, but trying to do so in the class definition.

```
class nextbutton(QPushButton):

    window.count += 1
    print(window.count)
```

The two lines above are only executed when the button is *created* by the line below.

```
mybutton = nextbutton()
```

To get the effect you want, move these lines inside the `function` method which receives the signal when the button is pressed.

```
class nextbutton(QPushButton):

    def function(self):
        window.count += 1
        print(window.count)
        if window.count == 1:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(a)
        else:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(b)
```

Rather than referencing the window, you might want to store the count on the button object itself. This would allow you to have multiple copies of this button which each track their current count and behave accordingly.

```
class nextbutton(QPushButton):

    count = 0

    def function(self):
        self.count += 1

        if self.count == 1:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(a)
        else:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(b)
```

#### Multiple signals

The above still won't work how you want it however. The following section will connect the `a` and `b` functions to the `next4` clicked signal. Because you can have multiple slots attached to the same signal, this will now trigger 3 behaviours — rerunning the

```
        if self.count == 1:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(a)
        else:
            ui.next4.clicked.connect(b)
```

Remember that if you're here you've already triggered the signal. You can simply call through to the functions directly.

```
        if self.count == 1:
            a()
        else:
            b()
```

Some other suggestions

The following bit of your code is surprising. You have a button defined in your UI as `ui.next4`, yet here you're creating another button, just to hold a function which you use to call another function.

```
mybutton = nextbutton()
ui.next4.clicked.connect(mybutton.function)
```

You could eliminate the nextbutton and make it a function in it's own right:

```
def nextbutton_clicked(self):
    window.count += 1
    print(window.count)
    if window.count == 1:
        a()
    else:
        b()
```

Then just connect as follows

```
ui.next4.clicked.connect(nextbutton_clicked)
```

Finally, I'd recommend renaming `nextbutton` to `NextButton` as it's a class. This is just a convention, but it's a good one to learn as it makes your code easier to read. Also, I'd recommend a different name for your method which is triggered by the button, `button_clicked` or similar.